# Anki fails to import from .csv file

Tags: csv, import, anki

I have created an custom note type containing 3 fields: Character, Pinyin and Definition.
I have a .csv file containing a few entries. The fields are comma-delimited.

Here's what I am presented when I try to import the file:

[image]

The mapping looks fine.

And here's how Anki fails to import:

[image]

Apparently it doesn't import anything at all. So, to debug I reduced my file to this:

```
爸爸,bàba,papa dad father
杯子,bēizi,cup glass
北京,běijīng,Beijing (Peking)
```

That's right, even importing these 3 lines fails.

So what is wrong?

Comment: What happens when you leave out the chinese characters?

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but the the Chinese characters shouldn't matter for anki, there are plenty of decks containing Chinese characters or other scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this.  You need to modify your note type so that it generates cards from the fields in the note.
Go to Manage Notes Types and select the note you want to use. 
Add or modify at least one card that uses at least one field from the note.